# TypeScript: Declare a variable with type of object literal

Tags: typescript

I am trying to find proper signature (current version of TypeScript is 1.7) for function that should accept only reference types, not primitives:

```
function onlyObject(x: ???) {
    if (typeof x !== 'object') {
        throw "bad arg!";
    }
}
```

So for function above this should work:

```
onlyObject({ });
onlyObject(new Date());
onlyObject(new Number(1));
onlyObject(null);
onlyObject(function () { });
```

but this will fail in compile time:

```
onlyObject("awd");
onlyObject(1);
onlyObject(false);
```

Comment: there is a type called Object, but last I heard there was a bug in typescript that allowed anything to be sent when used.

Comment: function onlyObject(x: Date | Number | void | Function){} ????? I don't believe TypeScript differentiates between a number and a Number or a string and a String, so you might have to exclude those. Or maybe rethink how you are approaching the problem. Ideally you only have a single type for a single variable.

Comment: Also, onlyObject(1) and onlyObject(new Number(1)) are pretty much the same in JavaScript since they both act as objects when they are treated as one, once they are assigned to a variable.

Comment: @Jon49 Well, I'd like to have a function for which `typeof x === 'object'` is true. Regarding differentiation between `string` and `String` - TypeScript does a bit, you can check it here: http://bit.ly/1ZBweTs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There currently isn't a way to express this in the language.

If you're feeling industrious, you can [add it](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1809), as the project is accepting pull requests for this feature.